# set index for dataframe created from pivot

Tags: pandas

I'm using pivot to create a new data frame, but I can't get the index how I want it.

Data:

```
dict = {'table_name': {0: 'emp', 1: 'emp', 2: 'emp'},
'date_captured': {0: '5/1/2019', 1: '5/2/2019', 2: '5/3/2019'},
'column_name': {0: 'unit', 1: 'unit', 2: 'unit'},
'value': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

new dataframe by pivoting df:

```
p = df.pivot(index='table_name',columns='date_captured',values='value')
```

new "p" dataframe looks like this:

```
date_captured   5/1/2019    5/2/2019    5/3/2019
table_name          
emp             1           1           2
```

I now want to remove the 'date_captured' label, have only one index level, and keep 'table_name' as the index.

dataframe should look like this and the index name should be "table_name":

```
table_name  5/1/2019    5/2/2019    5/3/2019
emp         1           1           2
```

tried resetting the index but I can't get rid of "date_captured":

```
p.reset_index(inplace=True)
p
```

"p" dataframe now looks like this:

```
date_captured   table_name  5/1/2019    5/2/2019    5/3/2019
0               emp         1           1           2
```

How do I get rid of 'date_captured' and get my dataframe to look like this:

```
table_name  5/1/2019    5/2/2019    5/3/2019
emp         1           1           2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then using `rename_axis`

```
p=p.rename_axis(None,axis=1)
p
Out[363]: 
            5/1/2019  5/2/2019  5/3/2019
table_name                              
emp                1         1         2
```